# How to derivate a matrix which its elements are functions?

Tags: function, matrix, fortran, subroutine, derivative

I'm using fortran and I'm trying to take a derivative of a matrix which its elements are functions.

```
    program derivada_matrix

    integer, parameter :: matrix_size = 5
    integer :: i,j
    real(8) :: time = 1.0
    real(8),dimension (matrix_size, matrix_size) :: W
    real(8),dimension (matrix_size, matrix_size) :: dW

   call potent(time,W)
   do i = 1, matrix_size
      do j=1, matrix_size
         call Derivada(time,W(i,j),dW(i,j))
       end do
   end do

   print*, 'matrix'
   print*, W
   print*, 'derivada', dW


   end program


  Subroutine Derivada (x1,F,D)
  implicit none
  Real*8 :: x1
  Real*8 :: h= 1.0E-6
  integer, parameter :: matrix_size = 5
  real*8 :: D,F
  external F
  D = (1.0*F(x1-2*h) - 8.0*F(x1-h) + 8.0*F(x1+h) -   1.0*F(x1+2*h))/(12.0*h)

 return
 End subroutine Derivada

 subroutine potent(T,W)
 implicit none
 integer, parameter :: matrix_size = 5
 real(8),dimension(matrix_size,matrix_size) :: W
 Real(8):: T
 integer :: i,j
 do i = 1, matrix_size
    do j=i,matrix_size
        W(i,j) = 0.0
        W(j,i) = W(i,j)
    end do
    W(i,i) = cos(T)
end do
RETURN
END subroutine potent
```

Basically the first subroutine creates a test matrix with a function (cosine) on the main diagonal and zeros elsewhere and the second subroutine it's supposed to derivate it.
This is the error/Warning message I get

```
      call Derivada(time,W(i,j),dW(i,j))
                      1
    Warning: Expected a procedure for argument ‘f’ at (1)
```

The error/warning message I get is in the second call. I guess because when I create the W matrix, it losses its property as a function and then I can't use as an argument in the second call to derive each element. 
How can improve it?
How can I make a program/function subroutine that its input is a matrix like this and its output would be its derivative???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't do what you think it does. `W` is just a an array of reals. You're just filling the entries with cos evaluated at the point `T`. It is not an array of functions.

Here's a more modern approach to what you want to do. Instead of using extern functions, it uses procedure pointers and wraps them in a derived type so you can create an array of them. Then you point to the functions you want it to take the derivatives of.

The limitation of this approach is that you must abide by the interfaces, in this case it will only work with functions that accept one double argument. You could expand this in several ways such as using optional arguments, wrapping them in a derived type, or using multiple interfaces, but that's up to you.

```
module deriv
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
  implicit none

  ! Wrapper for a procedure pointer so we can make an array of them
  type ptr_wrapper
     procedure(f), nopass, pointer :: func
  end type ptr_wrapper


  ! Use an interface for the function rather than "extern" functions
  ! Change the interface to whatever you want. You could take multiple reals, integers, etc
  abstract interface
    pure function f(x1)
       import
       real(dp), intent(in) :: x1
       real(dp) :: f
     end function f
  end interface


contains

  function derivada(x1, fx) result(d)
    implicit none
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x1
    procedure(f), pointer :: fx
    real(dp) :: d

    real(dp) :: h = 1.0E-6

    d = (1.0*fx(x1-2*h) - 8.0*fx(x1-h) + 8.0*fx(x1+h) -   1.0*fx(x1+2*h))/(12.0*h)

  end function derivada


  pure function test_func(x1)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x1
    real(dp) test_func

    test_func = 2d0 * x1
  end function test_func

  pure function test_func2(x1)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x1
    real(dp) test_func2

    test_func2 = x1**2
  end function test_func2


end module deriv

program derivada_matrix
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
  use deriv
  implicit none

  integer i, j
  real(dp) :: dx


  type(ptr_wrapper) :: w(2,2)

  !Point to the function that you want each index to point to
  w(1,1)%func => test_func
  w(1,2)%func => test_func2
  ! Pointing to the generic function wasn't working so I had to point to the specific double value trig functions
  w(2,1)%func => dcos 
  w(2,2)%func => dsin  

  do i = 1, 2
     do j = 1, 2
        dx = derivada(1d0, w(i,j)%func)
        print *, dx
     end do
  end do


end program derivada_matrix
```

And it prints out the derivative for these functions at x=1.0

```
  2.00000000000000     
  2.00000000011102     
 -0.841470984776962     
  0.540302305853706
```

Comment: I'll try and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Pd.: I don't understand why you commented that it doesn't work to point to the generic function. You could print the results correctly, what was that what wasn't working?

Comment: @Daniel I was getting weird values like 10^-300 when pointing to the generic function using  ifort 17

Comment: Always write all floating point constants with the `_dp` suffix: `1.0_dp, 3.5_dp, 1.34e8_dp` and never any other way. See: http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html